# backbone + jquery: How to retrieve data from the link with backbone's router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, custom-data-attribute, jquery-1.9

How can I retrieve data from the link with backbone's router? for instance,

html,

```
<a href='#!article/edit/about-us/' data-type="post">Edit</a>
```

backbone,

```
routes: {
        '!article/edit/:url/':    'renderDynamicPage'
    },

    renderDynamicPage: function (url) {
        console.log(url);
        var $this = this;
        $($this).click(function(){
           console.log($this.data("type"));
        });
    },
```

result,

```
about-us
```

but I want to get `post` from the data attribute. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. By the time the router knows about the location change, any reference to the `<a>` is long gone. Anything the router needs should be in the route itself:

```
routes: {
    '!article/edit/:url/(:type)': 'renderDynamicPage'
}
```

and the link would look like:

```
<a href='#!article/edit/about-us/post'>Edit</a>
```

If you can't do anything about the `<a>`s before they get on the page then you could kludge something up like this:

```
$('a[data-type]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('href', $this.attr('href') + $this.data('type'));
});
```

to patch the `href`s. Alternatively, you could add `click` handlers to all the `<a>`s you care about and manually merge the `data-type` into the URL fragment before updating `window.location`.